# Log4j FileNotFoundException - How Java FileSystem getBooleanAttributes() method works?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, log4j, filesystems

**Issue:**

I checked out the same maven project in 2 different workspaces. Imported into eclipse. Cleaned. Built them. Published to Tomcat.

While starting the server, one setup is able to find the log4j path (linux like). Another exact setup is NOT able to find the path and throws the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'log4jInitialization' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.50-old/wtpwebapps/DevCom-War/WEB-INF/lib/DevCom-Remittance-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/config/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Log4j config file [/home/deployment/devcom/config/devCom_log4j.properties] not found
```

If I add a `D:` in front of `/home/deployment/devcom/config/devCom_log4j.properties` in `devCom.properties`, only then the other setup recognises the path and does not throw the error.

> Why the first setup is able to recognise and use the linux like path
>   and the second setup does not?
>
> Out of all the involved entities, where the problem might lie?
>   Eclipse,Maven,Tomcat,SVN Eclipse Plugin ...?

**Tomcat configuration in eclipse:(Use Tomcat installation)**

```
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xms712m -Xmx712m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=356m -Dcatalina.base="D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.50-old" -Dcatalina.home="D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.50-old" -Dwtp.deploy="D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.50-old\wtpwebapps" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.50-old\endorsed" -Dext.prop.dir="D:\home\deployment" -Denv.prop="dev"
```

**Spring Config:**

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>file:///${ext.prop.dir}/devcom/config/devCom.properties</value>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
</bean>


<bean id="log4jInitialization" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
      <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer"/>
      <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging"/>
      <property name="arguments">
         <list>
            <value>${log4j.config.location}</value>
            <value>${log4j.refresh.interval}</value>
         </list>
      </property>
</bean>
```

**D:\home\deployment\devcom\config\devCom.properties:**

```
log4j.config.location = /home/deployment/devcom/config/devCom_log4j.properties
```

(Please note the linux like path.)

```
log4j.refresh.interval = 100000
```

**Project details:**

Windows 10

JDK 8

Spring 3.0.5

Tomcat 7

Maven

Eclipse Mars

**Log4jConfigurer initLogging:**

```
public static void initLogging(String location, long refreshInterval) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String resolvedLocation = SystemPropertyUtils.resolvePlaceholders(location);
    File file = ResourceUtils.getFile(resolvedLocation);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Log4j config file [" + resolvedLocation + "] not found");
    }
}
```

**File exists():**

```
public boolean exists() {
    SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (security != null) {
        security.checkRead(path);
    }
    if (isInvalid()) {
        return false;
    }
    return ((fs.getBooleanAttributes(this) & FileSystem.BA_EXISTS) != 0);
    // first setup -> 3 & 1. second setup -> 0 & 1 !!! What does it mean? How does it work?
}
```

Finally How does `getBooleanAttributes` method work? Will it be helpful to narrow down the source of this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`FileSystem`'s `getBooleanAttributes` returns:

> Return the simple boolean attributes for the file or directory denoted
>     by the given abstract pathname, or zero if it does not exist or some
>     other I/O error occurs

What this means is that it returns the sum of `read: 4`, `write: 2` and `execute: 1` (for example, all three being available means 7).

I would expect the behavior of your *second* setup as normal under Windows, that is the expected way of specifying an `absolute` path.

I suggest that you try to spot the configuration difference between your two environments: configuration options, user permissions, file system access, etc

Comment: I knew the problem could be the difference in configuration settings but was not able to guess where it might be. Finally narrowed it down. `Tomcat -> Open Launch Configuration -> Arguments -> Working Directory(Default)`. First setup : `D:\eclipse` Second Setup: `C:\WINDOWS\system32`. 1) What is the use of this working directory? 2) Why the default of the tomcat got changed to `C:` drive